# Unserialize array multidemensional en PHP

Tags: php

Basándome en este [post](http://manelperez.com/programacion/pasar-array-por-post-con-php/) estoy intentando enviar un resultado de un formulario en php a otra pagina php que se encarga de exportar este resultado a word.

Para esto primero obtengo el resultado de manera correcta, y para enviarlo a la otra página lo hago así:

```
<form action="pruebaExportar.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="resultado" value="<?php echo serialize($resultado) ?>" >
                <input type="submit" value="word">
            </form>
```

Esto en un principio no parece generar ningún error. El problema viene cuando en el otro php hago lo siguiente:

```
$resultado = $_POST['resultado'];
$resultado = unserialize(stripslashes($resultado));
```

Esto tampoco me genera errores pero cuando quiero acceder a un dato del resultado asi:

```
$resultado[$cont2]["NOMBRE"];
```

No saca ningún nombre.

*Aclaración: la variable `$cont2`es el indice de un `for`que va recorriendo los resultados.*

Por lo que he podido leer el problema esta cuando intento deserializar el array multidimensional por lo que enviarlo y recibirlo se hace de manera correcta pero luego no soy capaz de deseriazilarlo.

Comment: ¿Quieres hacerlo en HTML puro o puedo darte también una solución jQuery/XHR?

Comment: @OscarGarcia en un principio no tendria problema con jQuery, pero me gustaría saber ambas respuestas. Aun así me corroe una duda, ¿Como resuelves un problema de PHP con html?

Comment: Estoy en ello, un segundo que estoy escribiendo bastante literatura x)

Comment: Prueba el último ejemplo, `serialize()` / `base64_encode()` / `<textarea>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los pasos que debes seguir para enviar un campo de formulario en HTML con datos serializados desde PHP son:

- Codificar la información para transmitirla con [`serialize()`](http://php.net/serialize) o [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode).
- Generar código HTML que pueda ser enviado en un formulario con [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) o [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/base64_encode).
- Decidir usar un contenedor `<input>` o `<textarea>`.

La mejor combinación es `serialize()` / `base64_encode()` / `<textarea>` (ver el último ejemplo).

---

**`serialize()`/`htmlspecialchars()`/`<input>`**

En este ejemplo uso `serialize()`, `htmlspecialchars()` y la etiqueta `<input>` (al igual que has intentado hacer tú mismo):

```
<?php
$resultado = [
    /* Si aquí ponemos "valor\0hola" falla la decodificación */
    1 => "valorhola",
    'hola' => [
        'uno' => 'dos',
        'tres' => 3,
    ],
];
$datos = serialize($resultado);
?><form action="pruebaExportar.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="resultado"
    value="<?= htmlspecialchars($datos) ?>" >
  <input type="submit" value="word">
</form>
```

En el lado de decodificación:

```
<pre><?php
var_dump(unserialize($_POST['resultado']));
?></pre>
```

Problemas:

- `unserialize()`/`htmlspecialchars()` pueden fallar en la decodificación de cadenas con contenido binario (imágenes, etc) debido al tratamiento que haga el navegador/servidor de los campos de formulario.

---

**`json_encode()`/`htmlspecialchars()`/`<input>`**

En este ejemplo uso `json_encode()`, `htmlspecialchars()` y la etiqueta `<input>`:

```
<?php
$resultado = [
    1 => "valor\0hola",
    'hola' => [
        'uno' => 'dos',
        'tres' => 3,
    ],
];
$datos = json_encode($resultado);
?><form action="pruebaExportar.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="resultado"
    value="<?= htmlspecialchars($datos) ?>" >
  <input type="submit" value="word">
</form>
```

En el lado de decodificación:

```
<pre><?php
var_dump(json_decode($_POST['resultado']));
?></pre>
```

Problemas:

- `json_encode()` puede cambiar tipos de dato `Array` a `Object` por tener índices no numéricos.

---

**`serialize()`/`base64_encode()`/`<textarea>`**

En este ejemplo uso `serialize()`, `base64_encode()` y la etiqueta `<textarea>`:

```
<?php
$resultado = [
    1 => "valor\0hola",
    'hola' => [
        'uno' => 'dos',
        'tres' => 3,
    ],
];
$datos = serialize($resultado);
?><form action="pruebaExportar.php" method="post">
  <textarea style="display: none;" name="resultado"><?=
    base64_encode($datos) ?></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="word">
</form>
```

En el lado de decodificación:

```
<pre><?php
var_dump(unserialize(base64_decode($_POST['resultado'])));
?></pre>
```

Cualquier dato binario estará codificado en `base64`, caracteres normales, por lo que no se producirán problemas al decodificar datos sea cual sea el tratamiento que haga el navegador o el servidor al campo del formulario.

Problemas:

- La codificación [`base64`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) genera cuatro caracteres ASCII en su salida (6 bits/carácter x 4 caracteres = 24 bits) por cada tres caracteres de entrada (8 bits/carácter x 3 caracteres = 24 bits). Lo que es lo mismo, aumenta el tamaño de los datos enviados en un 33% (más los caracteres `=` de relleno de los últimos bits sobrantes hasta completar los cuatro caracteres de salida, prácticamente despreciable).

Comment: Iba a decirte que no funciona ninguna pero era porque no se habia borrado los datos de la cache ajajaj. Funciona correctamente, muchas gracias, ahora mismo estoy usando el tercer ejemplo pero supongo que todos funcionaran si no soy tonto de no resetear la cache.

Comment: Me alegra saber que te funciona. Es la mejor combinación, pero que sepas que se puede enviar también desde PHP de manera directa la petición a `pruebaExportar.php` con un `include` o mediante `curl`. Hacerlo de esta manera quizá no sea la idónea.