# Exportar a .csv desde Tabla

Tags: php, html, mysql

estoy actualmente intentando hacer un trabajo para un amigo, pero no consigo hacer lo siguiente.
Tengo una tabla donde esta todo lo que hay en la base de datos.
[image: Tabla Imagen]
Y el codigo de esa pagina es este (Pide una conexion que si funciona):
**index.php**

```html
<?php
 require('conexion.php');
 
 $query="SELECT *  FROM umg511_tbl";

 $resultado=$mysqli->query($query);
 
?>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Usuarios</title>
<style type="text/css">


/* Datagrid */
 body {
  font: normal medium/1.4 sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient( 0deg, #C0C0C0   , #F8F8F8);}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
th, td {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}
.centro{
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background: #484848 ;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 21px;

}

#cuadro{
 width: 90%;
 background: #F8F8F8 ;
 padding: 25px;
 margin: 5px auto;
 border: 3px solid #D8D8D8;
}
#titulo{
 width: 100%;
 background: #282828;
 color:white;

}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="cuadro">
  <div id="titulo">
  <center><h1>Regristos</h1></center>
  </div>
  
  <table>
   <thead>
    <tr class="centro">
     <td>ID</td>
     <td>Dia</td>
     <td>Descargar</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
     <?php while($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
      <tr>
       <td name="id">
        <center> <?php echo $row['umg511_id']; ?> </center>
       </td>
       <td name="fecha">
        <center><?php echo $row['umg511_day'];?></center>
       </td>
       <td name="descargar">
        <form action="hola.php" method="post" id="enviar">
         <center><input type="submit" value="Descargar" /></center>
        </form>
       </td>
      </tr>
     <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
   </table> 
   </center
  </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Lo que me gustaría hacer es que al darle al botón descargar, me cogiera la ID y buscara en la base de datos que coincide con esa id y bajara la row correcta.
He mirado algunos post de aquí, pero ninguno me ayuda (Intente seguir el que estaban con un select, pero no consigo adaptarlo aqui).

---

Añado el php para exportar al csv:
**hola.php**

```html
<?php
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

$list = null;
$dbname = "umg511";
$host = "localhost";
$user = "XX"
$pass = "XX"

try     
 {
 // Include globals from credentials.
 //global $dbname, $host, $user, $pass;

// Set up on database switch
$conn = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$host", $user, $pass);
$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");


        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
                                }

 // Define and perform the SQL SELECT query
  $sql = 'SELECT umg511_text FROM umg511_tbl';
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

 // If the SQL query is succesfully performed ($result not false)
  if($result !== false) 
  {
    $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);
    $headers = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
    $headers[] = mysql_field_name($result , $i);             
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    if ($fp && $result) {
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header('Expires: 0');
        fputcsv($fp, $headers);

        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
        }

        $conn = null;        // Disconnect
        die;
    }
   }
 }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Que es lo que te falla?La exportación o que no te sale ningún campo al exportar?

Comment: Que le doy a "descargar" y sale que no funciona la pagina, ni descarga nada...

Comment: Te voy a pasar una solución a partir de algo que ya tengo hecho, seguramente tengas que cambiar cosillas.

Comment: Vale, mientras ire probando cosillas, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías intentar con esto, en esta parte del codigo:

```
            <?php while($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){ 
            $datos = serialize($row);//Serializamos la columna
            $dato64 = base64_encode($datos);//La pasamos a base 64    
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td name="id">
                        <center> <?php echo $row['umg511_id']; ?> </center>
                    </td>
                    <td name="fecha">
                        <center><?php echo $row['umg511_day'];?></center>
                    </td>
                    <td name="descargar">
                        <form action="hola.php" method="post" id="enviar">
                            <center><input type="submit" value="Descargar" /></center>
                            <textarea style="display:hidden" name="resultado">'.$dato64.'</textarea>//Añadimos la columna en un textarea oculto
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
```

Añadiendo estas lineas pasaras la *row* completa codificada a **hola.php**.

Ahora la parte de la exportación:

```
$row= unserialize(base64_decode($_POST['resultado']));
header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-type:   application/x-msexcel; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Documento.xls"); 
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); 
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td name="id">
                        <center> <?php echo $row['umg511_id']; ?> </center>
                    </td>
                    <td name="fecha">
                        <center><?php echo $row['umg511_day'];?></center>
                    </td>           
                </tr>
            </table>
```

En un principio con esto deberia pasarte los datos de tu php principal al que exporta y mostrar los datos correctamente. Si quieres probar que los datos lleguen te recomiendo comentar los `header` y hacer:

```
var_export($row);
```

Y si quieres probar que exporte correctamente puedes dejar las cabeceras y crear una tabla html sin php (con datos escritos a mano).

Tambien te añado una pregunta que hize en la que se explica mejor el tema de serializar y codificar por si algo te fallara : [Unserialize array multidemensional en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67618/unserialize-array-multidemensional-en-php)

<sub>Si en la primera consulta recibes el texto en el segundo php en teoria no te hace falta ejecutar ninguna consulta, no se como tienes organizado el array con los resultados.</sub>

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias. Aparentemente con esto y unos cambios que he añadido para que no de error, funciona correctamente. Muchisimas gracias :D

Comment: @PepeFlanco De nada, un placer :3

Answer (score 0):

En el formulario usa un input hidden con el id.

```
<input name="idOculto" id="idOculto" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['umg511_id']; ?>" />
```

Luego cuando recuperes los datos del formulario unicamente tienes que hacer:

```
$idDescargar = $POST['idOculto'];
```

La parte de obtenerlo de la BBDD dependera de como tengas las conexiones y la capa de acceso a Datos. Luego solo tienes que descargar los datos en el formato que necesites.

Comment: He editado el post añadiendo el archivo hola.php que es el que supuestamente hace el boton...

Comment: En tu sql usa un where para obtener solo los datos de ese registro

Comment: ¿Como? No se a que te refieres con eso...

Comment: Tu query ahora mismo se trae todos los valores, pues lo que tienes que hacer es poner un WHERE <<columna>> = <<valor>>

Comment: Me podrias decir donde? Es que de mysql voy un poco corto...

Comment: Tienes que ampliar la query $sql = 'SELECT umg511_text FROM umg511_tbl'.

Comment: Una cosa asi? $sql = 'SELECT umg511_text FROM umg511_tbl WHERE umg511_id'.

Comment: SELECT umg511_text FROM umg511_tbl WHERE umg511_id = <<valor recuperado del formulario>>

Comment: Pero ese valor tendria que definirlo estaticamente? Es decir, si siempre es 1, siempre me va a descargar lo que esta en la row de umg511_id que es igual a 1... no?

Comment: Seria lo siguiente?  $sql = 'SELECT umg511_text FROM umg511_tbl WHERE umg511_id = id_oculto';

Comment: $idOculto = $POST['idOculto']; y luego "SELECT umg511_text FROM umg511_tbl WHERE umg511_id = ".$idOculto;

Comment: Gracias @Lithorell pero ya lo he solucionado. Un saludo :D